# why "adb shell ls /sdcard" return diffrent results

Tags: shell, return, adb

```
$ adb shell ls /sdcard/*|wc -l
42

$ adb shell ls /sdcard/|wc -l
25
```

I payed 2 commands through adb above, but gives 2 different results.

Some folder, for example "LOST.DIR" will appear in `/sdcard/` but not in `/sdcard/*`

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is showing you everything in the sdcard directory, PLUS everything in one level of directories below that.  That's also why LOST.DIR disappears; because there's nothing in it.

Consider that ls /sd* would show you the content of the sdcard directory; that might help understand what's happening here.  Wildcard expansion happens before running the external program ls.